# Does c2dm still work?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm

I'm working with some legacy code not used for a while. There's Android Push based on c2dm and it's not working - conection is refused while authenticating. Can it be because of discontinuation of c2dm?

Comment: Obvious question, but are you sure the authorization key you use in the request header is the correct api key?

Comment: Also, it could be that your clientlogin auth token has simply expired: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2012/04/android-c2dm-client-login-key.html